# ERROR: Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

I am facing a problem while building from Gradle. This is the error which I am facing:

> ERROR: Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.

Here is my Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.accedegh.retrofitlibrary"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.0'
implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'compile 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Top-level `build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. 
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        jcenter() 
        google() 
    } 

   dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' 
       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong 
       // in the individual module build.gradle files 
   } 
} 

allprojects { 
    repositories { 
        maven { 
            url 'maven.google.com' 
            name 'Google' 
        } 
    } 

    task clean(type: Delete) { 
        delete rootProject.buildDir 
    } 
}
```

Please give me the solution if anyone knows.

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the gradle file. Did you try to clean your project separately with the `Run>Clean Project` button ? What does it return ?

Comment: returns the same error when i clean the project

Comment: Can you post the other gradle file ?

Comment: Do a search in your Gradle files for the word `clean` and post that section of code in your question, you can probably remove the gradle file you've already posted from your question as I don't think it has any relevance to the problem.

Comment: Should we remove the irrelevant snippet now that there's a correct answer for the actual problem?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have this task defined in your project-level `build.gradle` (as posted in your comments):

```
task clean(type: Delete) { 
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

Android Studio's Gradle wrapper already has a `clean` task defined, so there's no need to re-define it. Just delete that task from your project-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Why does Android Studio auto add a clean task?